# Ansible DRY (don't repeat yourself)

Tags: ansible

I have 2 roles both with a list of tasks.

However, SOME (not all) of the tasks in role A are almost identical to the tasks in role B

Example role A task:

```
- name: Ensure bible server is running
  command: npm run forever
  args:
    chdir: ~/bible-server
  when: "foreverlist.stdout.find('bibleServer.js') == -1"
```

Example role B task:

```
- name: Ensure certs server is running
  command: npm run forever
  args:
    chdir: ~/certs-server
  when: "foreverlist.stdout.find('certsServer.js') == -1"
```

Is it possible to parametise a task such that I can declare a task like I would declare a function and pass in arguments to it?

Comment: That's what variables are for. I'm totally confused with the question.

Comment: If it's about defining one task and calling it from different roles, that's a matter of sanity. You would repeat the colon several times in the code anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Ansible this is what the inventory is for. Specify the configuration as variables in the inventory, If both roles are on the same host, you could use a dictionary. Then iterate through the dictionary to repeat the task on each configuration.

In the [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html):

```
servers:
  - path: bible-server
    script: bibleServer.js
  - path: cert-server
    script: certServer.js
```

Then in the task:

```
- name: Ensure Servers are running
  command: npm run forever
  args:
   chdir: "~/{{ item.path }}" 
  when: "foreverlist.stdout.find('{{ item.script }}') == -1"
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"
```

That's the high level overview. I would highly recommend reading up on the [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) because it's use is a core principle of Ansible. Also read up on [loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html).

Comment: But OP has two different roles with some, not all, tasks being the same. How does it answer this?